# Apache POI: Changing a runs picturetext

Tags: java, apache, apache-poi

I am trying to replace some text throughout a word document. I do this through iterating through XWPFRun runs, in most cases I can use 
run.setText(replacedText, 0) to replace the text. However, in some cases the text I want to replace is in run.getPictureText() rather than run.getText(). Unforunately, run.getPictureText() does not have a run.setPictureText() function counterpart like run.getText()'s run.setText(). Is there a way to go about replacing picture text?

Comment: This can't be answered that general. The [pictureText](https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/poi/tags/REL_4_0_1/src/ooxml/java/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.java?view=markup#l102) is a concatenation of all the plain texts within the pictures or drawings that XWPFRun contains. In case of pictures that might be texts in the single parts of an equation. In case of drawings that might be texts in single parts of an WordArt object. While this texts can easy be read and concatenated but not reasy be set. So first thing to do is determinating what kind of `pictureText` exactly needs to be replaced.

Comment: Ideally I would like to replace all of them. I'm trying to make a find and replace that replaces all instances, regardless of where they are found.

Comment: I believe the current one I am having issues with is in a text box though for starters

Comment: If you follow the link I gave in first comment, you find the code how `pictureText` is concatenated. Are you able finding your text when you are printing out all `kids.item(n).getNodeValue()`? If so `kids.item(n)` is [org.w3c.dom.Node](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html) which provides `setNodeValue` also.